# How to handle Unrecognized Property Exception for all the resources

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am parsing JSON using `Jakson` but it is throwing `UnrecognizedPropertyException` for Unrecognized field "publish" I have added  `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` for the element `resourceType` how can manage it for all the resources ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the appropriate `DeserializationFeature` to `false`.

```
new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Comment: Is it efficient?
Where should I declare this statement ?

Comment: @WaseemFarooqui What do you mean? As opposed to what?

Comment: Apposed on parsing the JSON don't you think annotations are more better than making it false.

Comment: @WaseemFarooqui If you want to annotate each of your types, sure. You asked for a default behavior _for all the resources_.

Comment: What is `DeserializationFeature`?
Is it any built in class or the class which I need to deserialize ?

Comment: @WaseemFarooqui Please read the [javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html).